# Error running the Macro - Next without For

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running the below code and getting Next without For , I'm I missing something. I want to retain the four excel sheets which comes first namely
1. Sheet1
2. InvoicesConsolidated
3. Merge_Excel
4. Consolidated

Rest of the sheets were imported into excel and need to be consolidated into sheet name "Consolidated" and get deleted after consolidation. I try to include the sheets names which I don't want to delete and added end if results in error while executing.

**Code1:** (this code checks invoices in A range of sheet1 with invoices range in "invoicesconsolidated"  by filtering the K column and copying the filtered items into new sheet with sheet named with invoice number

```
Sub filter()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim Last As Long
Dim sht As String
Dim shtb As String


 sht = "InvoicesConsolidated"
 shtb = "Sheet1"

 'change filter column in the following code
 Last = Sheets(sht).Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
 Set rng = Sheets(sht).Range("A1:K" & Last)

 'Sheets(shtb).Range("A1:A" & last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy,   CopyToRange:=Range("AA1"), Unique:=True

  For Each x In shtb.Range([A2], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
  With rng
 .AutoFilter
 .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=x.Value
 .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

 Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
 ActiveSheet.Paste
 End With
 Next x

 'Turn off filter
 Sheets(sht).AutoFilterMode = False

 With Application
 .CutCopyMode = False
 .ScreenUpdating = True
 End With

 Sheets("InvoicesConsolidated").Select

 End Sub
```

**Code 2:** (this code actually, consolidates the sheets which created after matching invoices into one single sheet and deleting the rest of the sheets.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim shLast As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range
Dim StartRow As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' Delete the summary sheet if it exists.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' Add a new summary worksheet.
Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "Consolidated"

' Fill in the start row.
StartRow = 1

' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
' summary worksheet.
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
        If sh.Name <> "Merge_Excel" Then
            If sh.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
                If sh.Name <> "InvoicesConsolidated" Then


        ' Find the last row with data on the summary
        ' and source worksheets.
        Last = LastRow(DestSh)
        shLast = LastRow(sh)

        ' If source worksheet is not empty and if the last
        ' row >= StartRow, copy the range.
        If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then
            'Set the range that you want to copy
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))

           ' Test to see whether there are enough rows in the summary
           ' worksheet to copy all the data.
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
               MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
               "summary worksheet to place the data."
               GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If
            End If
            End If


            StartRow = 1
            ' This statement copies values and formats.
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

        End If
        End If
        End If


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If sh.Name <> "Merge_Excel" Then
    If sh.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
    If sh.Name <> "InvoicesConsolidated" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        If sh.Name <> "Consolidated" Then ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sh.Name).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If


Next

ExitTheSub:



' AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
DestSh.Columns.AutoFit
 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidated").Range("A1:K50000").Sort Key1:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidated").Range("A2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes



ReadOutlineCells
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
MsgBox ("Consolidated")
End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function ReadOutlineCells()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated").Range("A1:K10000")
With rng.Borders
.LineStyle = xlContinuous
.Color = vbBlack
End With
End Function'
```

Comment: You are checking if the sheet name equals `Merge_Excel` and it in you have a nested check to see if the name matches `Sheet1`. This will never be true, it is one or the other, not both at the same time. Did you mean to use a logical OR operator to get sheets whose name is either `Merge_Excel` or `Sheet1`?

Comment: I'd like to encourage you to have a look at the Rubberduck VBA project - especially [the indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation). It's a neat VBE add-in that helps produce better VBA code.

Comment: ` If sh.Name <> "Merge_Excel" Then    If sh.Name <> "Sheet1" Then     If sh.Name <> "InvoicesConsolidated" Then `
... Maybe you wanted to say `If sh.Name <> "Merge_Excel" And sh.Name <> "Sheet1" And sh.Name <> "InvoicesConsolidated" Then` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your multiple criteria of `If <> ...` in the section below:

```
If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
        If sh.Name <> "Merge_Excel" Then
            If sh.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
                If sh.Name <> "InvoicesConsolidated" Then
```

Could be easily replaced with a `Select Case` like in the code below:

```
Select Case sh.Name

    Case DestSh.Name, "Merge_Excel", "Sheet1", "InvoicesConsolidated"
        ' do nothing

    Case Else
        ' this is the scenario you are describing in your code
        ' rest of your code goes here

End Select
```

Answer (score 1):

If you correct your indentations, you'll find the problem much quicker.
I have made an attempt at it below and that led to some added rows and some deleted ones. I'm not sure if that is the logic you sought, but the message here is to keep your indentation in good shape *at all times* - especially while writing the code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim shLast As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range
    Dim StartRow As Long       
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    ' Delete the summary sheet if it exists.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Consolidated").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ' Add a new summary worksheet.
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "Consolidated"

    ' Fill in the start row.
    StartRow = 1

    ' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
    ' summary worksheet.
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then
            If sh.Name <> "Merge_Excel" Then
                If sh.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
                    If sh.Name <> "InvoicesConsolidated" Then
                        ' Find the last row with data on the summary
                        ' and source worksheets.
                        Last = LastRow(DestSh)
                        shLast = LastRow(sh)

                        ' If source worksheet is not empty and if the last
                        ' row >= StartRow, copy the range.
                        If shLast > 0 And shLast >= StartRow Then
                            'Set the range that you want to copy
                            Set CopyRng = sh.Range(sh.Rows(StartRow), sh.Rows(shLast))

                           ' Test to see whether there are enough rows in the summary
                           ' worksheet to copy all the data.
                            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                               MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the " & _
                               "summary worksheet to place the data."
                               GoTo ExitTheSub
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If


                StartRow = 1
                ' This statement copies values and formats.
                CopyRng.Copy
                With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                End With

            End If
        End If


        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        If sh.Name <> "Merge_Excel" Then
            If sh.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
                If sh.Name <> "InvoicesConsolidated" Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                    If sh.Name <> "Consolidated" Then ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sh.Name).Delete
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                End If
            End If
        End If


    Next

ExitTheSub:



    ' AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit
     'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidated").Range("A1:K50000").Sort Key1:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidated").Range("A2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes



    ReadOutlineCells
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    MsgBox ("Consolidated")
End Sub
```

Comment: I agree about indentations. And it seems that `End If` is also missing in original code for two `if` conditions.

Comment: Basically, I have list of sheets named with invoice numbers with purchase order number and data associated in each excel worksheets, I want to consolidate all into one sheet under same heading, and delete the sheets after consolidation. out of that few sheets which should not be deleted or not picked up during loop. so it is basically deleting the heading and copy only the rows.

Comment: Thanks all, I have made the changes to the code as recommended by Vincent G, Thanks all, each one have provided a different solution. It is very useful.